# How to lock single row only for update

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way by which we can lock only single row of the table (IN SQL SERVER 2008)

I am trying something like this

```
BEGIN TRAN

select TOP 1 from [TableName] with (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK)

COMMIT
```

But seems like SQL server is ignoring ROWLOCK and acquiring IU lock on page and IX on Table.

Your help will be appreciated :)

Comment: It has to take Intent locks on the higher level objects (that's what the I stands for) otherwise the whole locking system doesn't work.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question

I have a queue like scenerio ,where I have to select 1 row at a time and update its status.

As load on this table will be very high I want to acquire update lock on a single row which is selected, so that concurrent execution will be possible.

Problem is even after specifying (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK,READPAST) together my second transaction is waiting for first one to finish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With UPDLOCK hint, you are requesting an UPDATE lock, that's why your SELECT is stuck waiting for previous transaction to complete.
You should specify HOLDLOCK but not UPDLOCK:

```
select TOP 1 * from t1 with (ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
```

This will keep a shared lock and let other transaction select data, but not update it : if another session try to update a row that is locked with this shared lock, it will have to wait that you release the lock( end your transaction)

You can view locks with this query:

```
SELECT request_session_id ,
    resource_type ,
    DB_NAME(resource_database_id) AS DatabaseName ,
    OBJECT_NAME(resource_associated_entity_id) AS TableName ,
    request_mode ,
    request_type ,
    request_status
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS L
JOIN sys.all_objects AS A ON L.resource_associated_entity_id = A.object_id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update Production.Location with (ROWLOCK)
   set CostRate = 100.00
 where LocationID = 1
```

Use rowlock when you want to update that records.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question

I have a queue like scenerio ,where I have to select 1 row at a time and update its status.

As load on this table will be very high I want to acquire update lock on a single row which is selected, so that concurrent execution will be possible.

Problem is even after specifying (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK,READPAST) together my second transaction is waiting for first one to finish

Answer (score 2):

```
select TOP 1 from [TableName] with (ROWLOCK)
```

Comment: Let me rephrase my question

I have a queue like scenerio ,where I have to select 1 row at a time and update its status.

As load on this table will be very high I want to acquire update lock on a single row which is selected, so that concurrent execution will be possible.

Problem is even after specifying (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK,READPAST) together my second transaction is waiting for first one to finish

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/35078b68-86ad-454b-968d-ab466ac352a7/update-with-rowlock?forum=transactsql